# Issue while doing Login using AJax call in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, forms-authentication

I am trying to do login with ajax call in mvc , its working fine but once the session expires,then I click on any page it navigates to Login page and then m not able to do Login.
My JS code is as

```
function verifiedLogin() {

    loading();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Login/Proceed",
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: { UserName: document.getElementById('username').value, password: document.getElementById('password').value },
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (result) {

            //if (status.Success) {
            //alert('In SUccess');
            window.location.href = "/Home/SearchResult";
            //var a=window.location.href;
            //alert(a);
            //}
            //else {
            //    alert("Invalid Crediential");
            //    $('#overlay').remove();
            //}
        },
        error: function (result) {

            alert("Please enter valid credential ");
            $('#overlay').remove();
        }
    });
```

}

First time its working fine issue is when it logs me out after session expire, then my URL become

```
http://localhost:53791/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fJob%2fSearchJobQueue
```

If I remove returnurl from the url then its working, but I don't know from where it is adding.
Code in web.config

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/SearchResult" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

How can I remove this?

Please suggest.

Comment: That is how Forms authentication works. I believe you can remove it if you modify your Global.asax file. But I don't think it is good idea. Instead of that you can resolve issue about ajax call. Do you get any error when you try to login?

Comment: It never hit the success part after timeout always hit the error part of js